# How to Iterate through dataframe using f-strings?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, f-string, cfstring

Iterate through dataframe using f-strings

Imagine you have the following df:

```
d = {'KvK': [0.21, 0.13, 0.1], 'line amount#2': [0.0, 0.05, .05], 'ExclBTW': [0.5, 0.18, .05]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    KvK line amount#2   ExclBTW
0   0.21    0.00         0.50
1   0.13    0.05         0.18
2   0.10    0.05         0.05
```

Now, I want to input each KvK value into an API call.

I've tried the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    details = df(row)
    f"https://api.kvk.nl/api/v2/search/companies?user_key=ldbb&q=f{row['KvK']}"
```

However this does not work.

Desired output:

```
    KvK line amount#2   ExclBTW    APIoutput#1
0   0.21    0.00         0.50        0.21APIsampleAPIOutput
1   0.13    0.05         0.18        0.13APIsampleAPIOutput
2   0.10    0.05         0.05        0.10APIsampleAPIOutput
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'KvK': [0.21, 0.13, 0.1], 'line amount#2': [0.0, 0.05, .05], 'ExclBTW': [0.5, 0.18, .05]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

url = f"https://api.kvk.nl/api/v2/search/companies?user_key=ldbb&q=f"
df['APIoutput'] = url + df['KvK'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply to format your URL string like this:

```
df['APIOutput'] = df['KvK'].apply(lambda x: f"https://api.kvk.nl/api/v2/search/companies?user_key=ldbb&q=f{x}")
```